# Convergence in measure implies convergence in Frechet's distance

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and let's define:

$$d(f,g):=\int \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}\,d\mu\;\;\forall f,g\in M(X,S)$$

> I want to prove that if $f_n\ \xrightarrow[\mu]{} f\Rightarrow d(f_n,f)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$

Proof:
Since $f_n\ \xrightarrow[\mu]{} f$, we know that:
$$\forall \epsilon>0\;\; \text{fixed},\;\; \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n(\epsilon))=0\\
(\text{where}\;\; A_n(\epsilon)=\{x\in X:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\ge \epsilon\}\;\forall n\in\Bbb N)$$

So what I did is: since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n(\epsilon))=0$, $\forall\hat\epsilon>0\;\;\exists\ N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\; \mu(A_n(\epsilon))<\hat\epsilon\;\;\forall n\ge N$

So taking $A_0=\bigcup_{n\ge N}A_n(\epsilon)\Rightarrow\ \mu(A_0)=0$ and $\;\;\forall n\ge N\;\;|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\;\;\forall x\in X\setminus A_0$
Thus $f_n\to f\;\;a.e.-\mu$

But I don't know if I missed something from here. Any objections?

---

**Update 1**

So if there's no problem with what I proved above then:
Let $g_n=\frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$ so we get that:

$$(g_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset M(X,S),\;\;\; \text{since}\;\;\; f_n,f\in M(X,S)\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\\ g_n\to 0\;\;a.e.-\mu,\;\;\; \text{since}\;\;\; (f_n-f)\to 0\;\; a.e.-\mu\\
|g_n|=\frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}<1\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

and since $\mu(X)<\infty$ we apply the LDCT (Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem) $a.e.-\mu$ version and get that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n d\mu = \int 0d\mu = 0$$

but

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty} d(f_n,f)$$

thereby $d(f_n,f)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$

Comment: After you have $n \geq N \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon \quad \forall x \in X \backslash A_0$, you have to talk about $d(f_n, f)$:
$$
d(f_n, f) \leq \int_{X \backslash A_0} |f_n - f| \leq \varepsilon \mu(X)
$$